# Reprojecting a raster image using gdalwarp

Tags: raster, gdal, gdalwarp

I am trying to reproject an ECW Orthophoto from 25830 to 23030 srid. 
I tried the following but I am getting an error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\FWTools2.4.7>gdalwarp -s_srs 25830 -t_srs 23030 C:\orto.e
cw C:\orto_ed50.ecw
ERROR 1: Translating source or target SRS failed:
25830
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to specify the type of code that you are using. Here I guess that it is EPSG

C:\Program Files (x86)\FWTools2.4.7>gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:25830 -t_srs EPSG:23030 C:\orto.e
cw C:\orto_ed50.ecw

Comment: I suggest to update from FWtools to the more recent gisinternals SDK. The FWtools srs database does not get any update.